# How Can I Detect Any Object from Video Camera in IOS?

Tags: ios, opencv, augmented-reality

I am developing an application to identify object from the real world object. Is that possible to identify any object from video camera? Now on words I am using openCV library to identify object. But just recording a video it does not do anything. I am very poor about AR. Please suggest me what I have to do for the identifying a real world object if possible.

Comment: what objects are you going to detect? If you want to detect the face or people, there are some build in descriptor for detecting, like `cv2.HOGDescriptor()` and `cv2.CascadeClassifier()` For other objects, you can train your own classifier, please refer to [link](http://coding-robin.de/2013/07/22/train-your-own-opencv-haar-classifier.html)

Comment: i just want to detect any object. for e.g. lets take banana. i can detect faces from natively.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: follow [this](http://answers.opencv.org/question/8329/opencv-setting-ios-orientation/?answer=64134#post-id-64134) to setup your opencv camera

Step 2: add this code to processImage delegate

```
- (void)processImage:(cv::Mat&)image
{
      //process here
      cv::cvtColor(image, img, cv::COLOR_BGRA2RGB);
      int fixedWidth = 270;
     cv::resize(img, img, cv::Size(fixedWidth,(int)((fixedWidth*1.0f)*   (image.rows/(image.cols*1.0f)))),cv::INTER_NEAREST);

    //update the model
    bg_model->apply(img, fgmask, update_bg_model ? -1 : 0);

    GaussianBlur(fgmask, fgmask, cv::Size(7, 7), 2.5, 2.5);
    threshold(fgmask, fgmask, 10, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);

    image = cv::Scalar::all(0);
    img.copyTo(image, fgmask);
}
```

You'll need to declare following as global variable

```
cv::Mat img, fgmask;
cv::Ptr<cv::BackgroundSubtractor> bg_model;
bool update_bg_model;
```

Where, img <- smaller image fgmask <- the mask denotes that where motion is happening update_bg_model <- if you want to fixed your background;

for more detail go through this [link](http://www.intorobotics.com/how-to-detect-and-track-object-with-opencv/)